# Spring. Redirect to external url in controller without encoding

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am trying to make redirect to external URL in my controller:

```
return "redirect:" + url;
```

all works fine for common urls, but now I need to redirect for url which contain other url as parameter (partner program referrer url). I have configured `CharacterEncodingFilter` in my `web.xml`. And as I understand this filter encode my parameter url to `UTF-8` characters ('http://' encoded to 'http%3A%2F%2F'). This throw error in partner program.

How can I avoid encoding url in my controller?

Perhaps my conclusions contain errors?

Comment: You have stated it in question, but I want to confirm again is the url you are redirecting to is external to your application?

Comment: yes, on example:                                               `return "redirect:" + "http://site2.com/scripts/click.php?site=http://site3.com"`

Comment: I don't think there is any way to send this without escaping first.  Otherwise, it gets very confusing for the browser to interpret.  I think Apache Commons-Lang has some classes to escape URLs.  I would try escaping out the parts after "site=".